# How to plot mean and standard deviation of multiple lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot mean and standard deviation of the following three column.
The data file, named `std.txt`, is the above one

```
1       5       4       2
2       2       1       0
3       8       4       1
4       4       3       0
5       1       0       0
6       8       2       1
7       4       3       3
8       7       5       4
```

I used the following to plot three lines

```
plot 'std.txt' using 1:2 with lines, \
     'std.txt' using 1:3 with lines, \
     'std.txt' using 1:4 with lines
```

Now I want to plot the means and a shaded region in the region between [mean+standard deviation, mean-standard deviation].

Comment: Hi Kayan, try to be more precise and to give as many information as you can. E.g. which operative system are you using? Which version of _gnuplot_? What have you done for your purpose (mean and standard deviation) till now? It will help to give answer to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's we suppose you have computed mean and standard deviation for each column.
You can use something like the script below

```
# Computed values of means (Avg) and standard deviations (SD)
Avg2=4.875000;    SD2=2.471715
Avg3=2.750000;    SD3=1.561249
Avg4=1.375000;    SD4=1.408678

set termoption enhanced
set key below
set style fill transparent solid 0.40 noborder  # <------ Note transparent
set title "{/=14 Plot for Kayan}"               # Bigger
set xlabel "{/=12 X of Kayan data [a.u]}"       # Big  
set ylabel "{/=12 Y of Kayan data [a.u]}"       # Big

plot Avg2+ SD2 with filledcurve  y1=Avg2-SD2  t "Mean #2"  lc rgb "#00B000" \
   , Avg2                                     notitle lw 2 lc rgb "#00B000" \
   , 'std.txt' using 1:2 with lines           t "Data #2"  lc rgb "#008000" \
   , Avg3+ SD3 with filledcurve  y1=Avg3-SD3  t "Mean #3"  lc rgb "#00B0F0" \
   , Avg3                                     notitle lw 2 lc rgb "#00B0F0" \
   , 'std.txt' using 1:3 with lines           t "Data #3"  lc rgb "#00B0B0" \
   , Avg4+ SD4 with filledcurve  y1=Avg4-SD4  t "Mean #3"  lc rgb "#0000B0" \
   , Avg4                                     notitle lw 2 lc rgb "#0000B0" \
   , 'std.txt' using 1:4 with lines           t "Data #4"  lc rgb "#000080" \
#
```

and obtain a result similar to this:

### [image: Plot of means and data]

**Big Bonus:** awk code to generate the means and standard deviations.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=2; i<5; i++ ){n[i]=0; s[i]=0;    sq[i]=0;       } } \
          {for (i=2; i<5; i++ ){n[i]++; s[i]+= $i; sq[i]+=$i*$i ; } } \
       END{for (i=2; i<5; i++ ){printf("Avg%s=%f; SD%s=%f\n",i,s[i]/n[i], \    
                                i,sqrt(sq[i]/n[i]-s[i]^2/n[i]^2)) } }' std.txt
```